# Is it correct to say :He survived in a car crash. or should I say: He survived a car crash--without "in"

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering is it acceptable or correct to say "He survived in a car crash" since all the example sentences show that I need to cross out "in"--survive a car crash

Answer (score 2):

The usual form is *he survived a car crash*, using the **transitive** meaning of *survive*: "[4. *(transitive)* To live past a life-threatening event.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/survive)."

Your alternative *he survived in a car crash* is grammatical, but odd and hard to interpret. It is using the intransitive form "1. *(intransitive)* Of a person, to continue to live; to remain alive," but an adjunct phrase such as *in a car crash* would normally be interpreted as meaning where/when/how he was continuing to be alive, not anything about the circumstances in which his life was threatened.

So for example, you might get something like *He survived on the roof of his house*, talking about a flood: the roof was not the event that threatened his life (the meaning of the object of transitive *survive*) but the circumstances where/when/how he survived.